# Call Library function from html with google.script.run

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, libraries

I implement library with Google App Script and I have some difficulties to call a function from library using google.script.run.

Here is the code of my Library :

Code.gs

```
function ShowSideBar() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index_librairie').evaluate()
        .setTitle('Console de gestion')
        .setWidth(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .showSidebar(html);
}

function execution_appeler_par_html(){
  Logger.log("execution_appeler_par_html"); 

}
```

Index_librairie.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(work_off).execution_appeler_par_html(); 
    function work_off(e){
    alert(e);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    test de ouf
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Spreadsheet that use the Library : 
Code.gs

```
function onopen() {
  lbrairietestedouard.ShowSideBar();
}
```

Google.script.run does not reconize execution_appeler_par_html() function.
I should use libraryname.execution_appeler_par_html() but this syntaxe doesn't work in configuration of google.script.run

Comment: Have you tired a dummy function, which in turn calls `lbrairietestedouard.execution_appeler_par_html()`. Ex: `function dummy(){ lbrairietestedouard.execution_appeler_par_html() }` in your HTML side just `call google.script.run.dummy()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that **google.script.run** can't look inside Objects or self-executing anonymous functions. In my case, putting any code inside an object or IIFE resulted in "is not a function" type of error being thrown in the console.

You can work around this by declaring a single function that will call nested methods inside libraries and objects.

.GS file

```js
 function callLibraryFunction(func, args){

    var arr = func.split(".");
    
    var libName = arr[0];
    var libFunc = arr[1];
    
    args = args || [];
       
   return this[libName][libFunc].apply(this, args);

}
```

In JavaScript, every object behaves like an associative array of key-value pairs, including the global object that 'this' would be pointing to in this scenario. Although both 'libName' and 'libFunc' are of String type, we can still reference them inside the global object by using the above syntax. apply() simply calls the function on 'this', making the result available in global scope.

Here's how you call the library function from the client:

```js
 google.script.run.callLibraryFunction("Library.libraryFunction", [5, 3]);
```

I don't claim this solution as my own - this is something I saw at Bruce McPherson's website a while back. You could come up with other ad-hoc solutions that may be more appropriate for your case, but I think this one is the most universal.

Comment: I have an html form in parameter, it doesn't propagate with the `this[func].apply(param)`
I successfully used this alternative: `eval(func)(param)`

Answer (score 2):

Noticed the same problem trying to invoque library from google.script.run within HTML code.
Here is the workaround I use :

LIBRARY SIDE : aLibrary

```
function aFunction(){
    //code...;

}
```

---

ADDON SIDE (requires library "aLibrary")

```
function aFunction(){
    aLibrary.aFunction();

}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="run aFunction" onclick="google.script.run.aFunction()" />
```

I like the workaround because I keep a clear view and organisation of my functions names, and do not need to alter HTML code if I bring my functions directly inside the addOn project, once development is satsifying.

Only thing I did not try yet : handling arguments and return values....

I hope this contribution is not to foolish, please forgive me I am very amateur...

Answer (score 1):

After quite long time working on this, I found out that any function that you call from the library using `google.script.run` must exist in both the main script and the library script. The function must at least be declared in the main script while the implementation as well as the parameters are not important. The implementation will be in your library. If the main script does not include the name of the function, the error `<your function> is not a function` will appear.

Now that there is no meaning of having a library if every single function needs to exist in the main function, the solution provided by @Anton Dementiev would be used as a workaround. Suppose you have a function named `testFunc` in your library, you can call it using the following method:

```js
google.script.run.callLibraryFunction("testFunc", [5, 3]);
```

where the library has this function:

```
function callLibraryFunction(func, args) {
  args = args || [];
  return this[func].apply(this, args);
}
```

and the main script has this declaration:

```js
function callLibraryFunction() {

}
```

Google must fix this stupid behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue which I was directed to this thread for recently, and I tried numerous solutions... however, I came across another thread yesterday (which I unfortunately clicked out of / lost track of so I can't link to it) that had a proposed solution to a *different* problem I was facing with Libraries.

[Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20928225/angelo)'s answer on this thread is actually very close to what I found that worked for me, so please refer to his answer with one slight modification on the client-side/add-on side:

```js
function aFunction(){
    return aLibrary.aFunction();
}
```

For me, simply adding "return" in is what did the trick. This was an extremely simple solution (far more simple than many of the other options suggested) so I thought it'd be valuable to share for anyone else in my boat. It might not work for everyone (I haven't tested it fully yet) but it changed my "null" values to the expected array values that I wanted, so I'm satisfied with it for my simple/amateur needs. Not sure if it'll work with arguments, but at least for simple functions without arguments it gets the job done.

Update: I just tested it with a simple argument `array` where I updated both Lib/Client sides to accept the argument, set a variable on the client side's html script to `var testArray = ['opt 1', 'opt 2', 'opt 3']` and fed it into the function via the html script -- worked perfectly both ways and came out the other side in my html/JavaScript output. So I can confirm it should work even for functions with simple arguments at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as far as I can tell, is due to [hoisting](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html) - see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

> The difference is that functionOne is a function expression and so only defined when that line is reached, whereas functionTwo is a function declaration and is defined as soon as its surrounding function or script is executed (due to hoisting).

Evidently, `google.script.run` executes at a level prior to any variable declarations in *dependent* scripts. So yes, when using callbacks of the form `google.script.run.myWhateverCallback()` in a library, dependent scripts must define that callback as a hoistable function and not in a variable/constant declaration.

```
/* don't do this, as you might for your controller actions in the app menu */
const { myWhateverCallback, myOtherCallback } = MyParentLibrary;

/* do this instead, for *every* callback needed by google.script.run */
function myWhateverCallback()
  MyParentLibrary.myWhateverCallback(...arguments);
}
```

According to prior answers, the body of the function may be redundant since the final execution of the function *is in the scope of the parent library* - but I haven't tested this, and Google may yet fix it so I'm using the hoisted callback functions as actual wrappers just in case.