# Call Google Apps Script function from a Library with HTML/JavaScript in a GAS Project?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, libraries

I'm having trouble trying to call a Google Apps Script function that I have built into a Google Apps Script Library. I want to pull a simple array from my library script into a bound script that I've added the library to. At first, I thought I'd made some error in how I was handling everything, but I tested it outside of the Library and it **actually works**. I have a Code.gs file and a Test.html file that I used to test it in the local script.

Working code:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Test');
}

function setSelectOptions() {
  var options = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'];
  Logger.log('setSelectOptions got called.');
  return options;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function errorFunction(errorMsg) {
        console.log("ERROR - Check it!");
      }

      function successFunction(arrayText) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: " + arrayText);
        return arrayText;
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunction).setSelectOptions();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Working results in console log: `SUCCESS: option 1,option 2,option 3`

The non-working code only makes **one** change, using the same function from within my Library rather than the local script:

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunction).MyLibrary.setSelectOptions();`

But I get this result: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setSelectOptions') at userCodeAppPanel:10:75`

I'm not even sure if I'm formatting it properly or not, but I've been up and down google and these forums for the past few hours with no luck on finding a way to properly call a function (in HTML/JavaScript) from a Library, or any reason why it would work one way and not the other with such a simple function. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I thought that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48928932

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the methods in that thread and I'll update here if I find a solution (or if I can't find any solution).

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your suggestion! I tried all of the methods and the highest rated answer in that thread seems to work after I tested it (mostly). However, I realized I'm having one problem still: The `return arrayText;` in my successFunction is still returning as `undefined` even though it seems to be coming through fine in my console log line as `SUCCESS: [option 1, option 2, option 3]`. I'm not sure if this is a Library issue or if my problem is something else? I don't know if I should be returning the value differently somehow?

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: About your current issue of `The return arrayText; in my successFunction is still returning as undefined even though it seems to be coming through fine in my console log line as SUCCESS: [option 1, option 2, option 3].`, I deeply apologize for the inconvenience and my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot correctly imagine your current script from your reply, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not being clear. I'm using a success handler in this line of code, using the method in the thread you suggested :
`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunction).callLibraryFunction("MyLibrary.setSelectOptions");`

I added the callLibraryFunction described in that thread to my .gs code and it seems to work.

When I check the Apps Script Log, I get: `setSelectOptions got called.`
When I check the console log, I get: `SUCCESS: option 1,option 2,option 3`

These are as expected from my logs. However, logging the returned value in a variable gives `undefined`.

Comment: I apologize, my comment was a bit long to complete. For example:
`let options = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunction).callLibraryFunction("SidebarLibrary.setSelectOptions");` and `console.log("TEST: " + options);` returns in the console log as `TEST: undefined`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current script and issue. And, I cannot understand the relationship between `callLibraryFunction` and your showing script in your question. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide your current script and the details of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your new issue. I think that when I could correctly understand your current situation, I might be able to understand the reason for your current issue.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, I can provide more details. However, I think this thread is getting too long. Should I create a new topic since this is a slightly different issue? Or would it be alright to send you a private message with more details?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the reason for your current issue, `let options = ` of `let options = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunction).callLibraryFunction("SidebarLibrary.setSelectOptions");` was shown at the separate line in the comment. I think that your current issue is due to `google.script.run` returns no value. By this, `options` of `let options = google.script.run,,,` returns no value. In this case, please get the value from `callLibraryFunction` in the function `successFunction`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand that using `google.script.run` would return no value. Since I'm a bit of an amateur at this, I thought it would return the value of the successFunction. I'll look into this more so I can set it up properly this time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when you want to retrieve the values from Google Apps Script like `const res = ...`, this repository might be useful. https://github.com/tanaikech/syncGoogleScriptRun

Comment: And, when the thread of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48928932 resolves your question, I will flag this as a duplicate question.